# Forcing choice for default value during data entry

Tags: qgis, default, default-value, qgis-variable

Let's assume you have to perform different field surveys for different projects. For example, you have to log all sightings of birds for different projects.

During data entry of the bird sightings I would like to link the recorded sighting to a single projectnumber. But I would only like to enter this number once and not for each bird sighting. Once I leave the data entry mode all sightings should have been  linked to the project choosen. When I perform another field survey I need to enter the project number again once I start recording new sightings. So this default value varies depending on the moment you perform a field survey.

I can define a variable and use a formula to set a default value based on the variable value. But if you forget to change the variable then all sightings are linked to the wrong project. So in this case I would like to be forced to set a default value prior to data entry. Something like a pop-up menu before data entry. Is there a way to achieve this in QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will need some Python code to achieve it. You can connect the signal "editingStarted" - which will be emitted every time when the editstate is changing to be started - to a function, which will ask you for a project ID and set it to a project variable. Below you will find an example for that.

This script need to be run only once in your session, for example at the beginning or opening of your project. So one strategy could be, to put this script as an open-Project Python macro (see project->properties->macros):

```py
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsExpressionContextUtils
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Enter Variable")
        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        self.v_label = QLabel("Variable", self)
        self.v_field = QLineEdit(self)
        self.v2_label = QLabel("Variable 2", self)
        self.v2_field = QLineEdit(self)  
        self.ok_btn = QPushButton("OK", self)
        self.ok_btn.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.cancel_btn = QPushButton("Cancel", self)
        self.cancel_btn.clicked.connect(self.reject)
        btn_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        btn_layout.addWidget(self.ok_btn)
        btn_layout.addWidget(self.cancel_btn)
        layout.addRow(self.v_label, self.v_field)
        layout.addRow(self.v2_label, self.v2_field) 
        layout.addRow(btn_layout)
        self.setLayout(layout)

def setNewVariable():
    dialog = MyDialog()
    if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
        var = dialog.v_field.text()
        var2 = dialog.v2_field.text()
        project = QgsProject.instance()
        QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(project,'myvar',var)
        QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(project,'myvar2',var2)


def openProject():
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('contourlines_l')[0]
    # The Signal 'editingStarted' is connected to the function 'setNewVariable'
    layer.editingStarted.connect(setNewVariable)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Please note that I am not familiar with coding, so I am not really able to read the programming. So, my apologies if I am unable to fully understand the solution or if some of my questions make no sense.
I applied your solution. During the opening of the project the macro is activated. But I receive the following error: NameError: name 'QDialog' is not defined. Can you please help me solve this error?

In the end I need this logic only for a specific layer. I assume this coding could also be added under ‘actions’ using type ‘Python’?

Comment: Yes you are right, to use it in the project open macro and not from the console it need some adjustements. All classes must be loaded before. I have changed the script above, now it works as a project open script. You have to change some little things. In the "def setNewVariable():" you have to adjust the variable name to your requirements and in the "def openProject():" the name of the layer, in the example above it is "contourlines_l"

Comment: GREAT!! This works!! A big thank you! 
Maybe it is too much to ask but to make this 100% perfect:
1. Is it easy to extend this functionality to 2 variables (in my case Project_ID and Subproject_ID?
2. Is it possible to select the variable from an existing layer (Project_data) which includes these 2 fields?

Comment: Add 2 fields is not the much work (copy & paste) - see above code is changed, but to get all project ids and populate them within a drop down field will be a few more lines of code.

Comment: I aded the line "var2 = dialog.v2_field.text()" and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much for your great help!